# submitting a form multiple times

Tags: angularjs

I have a form. It submits reservations, but after it has done so, the application doesn't change locations. A table on the page does update, but that's it.

Here's the submit function:

```
vm.submit= function(){
    if(vm.reservationForm.$valid){
        // do stuff.
    }
};
```

This works for the first submit. The form object itself, `vm.reservationForm` is populated with the usual stuff ($valid, $pristine, etc).

But if I try to resubmit the same form--and again, the location hasn't changed, the page is still essentially the same--then `vm.reservationForm` is set to  `undefined`.

It appears that submitting the form destroys `vm.reservationForm`. Is this expected behavior? Am I missing something?

Comment: No, the form becoming undefined is not expected default behavior. In order for that to occur, the code must be setting it to undefined. Can you provide the full vm.submit implementation? and any other code/markup where vm.reservationForm is referenced?

Comment: No, that is not expected behavior. It's probably happening somewhere in the `// do stuff.`.